# Autocomplete dropdown of a text input box stays after the input is hidden with CSS

Tags: javascript, html, css, autocomplete

I use CSS `left: 9999em;` to hide a `<div>` and `left: 0em` to show it on hover.

The `div` contains a text input box. If the input box has an open autocomplete dropdown when I hide the `div` by removing the mouse, the autocomplete box still stays on the page.

How can I hide that one, too? CSS solution is preferable. (I think I know how to do it with jQuery.) I do *not* want to disable autocomplete for this box, I just want it to be gone when the box itself is gone.

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ou5cgzpv/

After double-click:

[image]

After removing the mouse:

[image]

Comment: Is there a reason you're not using the visibility css property?

Comment: @hobenkr I tries `visibility`, same effect. The reason is that I need a delay, and I use an animation for this (I don't know how to delay visibility change). But anyway, the effect is the same.

Comment: The problem I had running your example is after the text box was hidden, I accidentally hit my keyboard and the screen was zipped over to 9999em ;) As for your actual problem is there somewhere we could see a live example? Your dropdown doesn't work on the JSFiddle.

Comment: @hobenkr I updated the fiddle, so that you can first populate the autocomplete with some submits: http://jsfiddle.net/kqr0t3xn/.

Answer (score 1):

CSS - In this the `input` field is being hidden instead of your `inner` element being shifted to the right.

```
#container {
    width: 135px;
    height: 20px;
    background: green;
    padding: 10px;
}
input {
    display: none;
    width: 130px;
}
#container:hover input {
    display: block;
}
```

HTML Form

```
<div id="container">
<form id="form">
    <input type="text" name="autocomplete" />
</form>
```

Comment: Sorry, I tried your solution, but the effect is the same: http://jsfiddle.net/v1xtca2k/. I changed the name to `name` for it to have some autocomplete options.

Comment: Is it possible to show a working example of this (from the Internet) because I'm not understanding exactly what you are trying to do then.

Comment: I updated the fiddle, so that you can first populate the autocomplete with some submits: http://jsfiddle.net/kqr0t3xn/.

Comment: Update: this answer DOES work in Chrome. But NOT in Firefox. Any idea for Firefox?

Comment: Tested and worked in the following:  Opera 30.0.1835.88, Chrome Version 44.0.2403.61 beta-m (64-bit), Firefox 39.0 and IE11.

Comment: Am I right that this is a browser preference? That's why it seems to be browser dependent.

Comment: No. This SO question is related to the structure of the html and css. That documentation from Mozilla is specific to a users setting in the browser with regard to Autocomplete fields saving data the user previously entered.

Comment: @vanburenx In this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/v1xtca2k/, I see this: http://www.gelbukh.com/so/autocomplete.html. Note the list at the bottom left of the second image! Any ideas?

Comment: Are you testing it in Firefox or jsfiddle running in Firefox? And what library are you using for your Autocomplete functionality?

Comment: @vanburenx Here is a live example: http://www.gelbukh.com/so/x.html. No library. Works as expected in Chrome. In Firefox, leaves the autocomplete box. In IE, in addition lives a text cursor in the top left corner of the box, and you can type into non-existent input (what you type appears in the box if you hover on it again). To see the effect, use the Submit button to populate the autocomplete with some strings, and use double-click on the text box to show autocomplete, and then hover out.

Comment: @vanburenx Upvoting with thanks for a CSS solution for Chrome. Still can't accept this as answer because it only works in Chrome. Any ideas are welcome!

Answer (score 0):

In Chrome, as correctly pointed out by vanburenx, `display: none;` removes the autocomplete dropdown. In FireFox and IE it does not.

With JavaScript or jQuery, `blur()` the `input type=text` in `onmouseleave()` for the container; this removes the dropdown.

Any answer with pure CSS is still welcome!